# sql join question

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables, auctions and users.

I want to select the username table from auctions where category=x, and then select the fields a, b and c from the users table, where the username field in users matches th username fields from auctions.

I am trying this:

```
SELECT AUCTIONS.USERNAME, USERS.firstname, USERS.lastname, USERS.flaggedauctions
FROM AUCTIONS
INNER JOIN USERS
ON AUCTIONS.USERNAME=USERS.USERNAME
```

Which seems to work. However, USERNAME is not a primary key in either table, and in the auctions table there can be many records with the same username, as where there will be only one record per username in the users table.

The above query works, but the problem arises if I want to limit the result set to say 10, for pagination. This may result in 10 records returned, some of which are duplicates. Is there a way to run a query limiting to 1 record per surname inside of another query?

edit: in answer to Quassnoi's post

usernames are always unique

If I have

```
Auctions:
    username    category    blah
    -------------------------------------
    user1       category1   tshirt
    user2       category2   jeans
    user3       category3   shoes
    user2       category3   belt
    user3       category3   pants

Users:
    username    firstname   lastname
    -------------------------------------
    user1       john        smith
    user2       fred        black
    user3       alice       brady

Then given category 3 as the category, I would want to show:

    username    firstname   lastname
    -------------------------------------
    user2       fred        black
    user3       alice       brady

With username coming from the auctions table.

Instead, at the moment this will display:

    username    firstname   lastname
    -------------------------------------
    user2       fred        black
    user3       alice       brady
    user3       alice       brady
```

edit2:

I am using

```
SELECT username, firstname, lastname
FROM USERS
WHERE username
IN (

SELECT USERNAME
FROM AUCTIONS
WHERE category = 'fake'
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Which returns 0 results. There are certainly many records in AUCTIONS with category set to fake.

Comment: Could you provide the structure of the auction and user tables?

Comment: So hold on, is the username unique? You're saying it's not a PK in either table which makes it sound as if there can be duplicates, so whilst a SELECT DISTINCT would work, surely it wouldn't be valid if username isn't unique because you would inadvertently omit valid entries?

Answer (score 5):

I would advice to use `SELECT DISTINCT`, but I rather ask you this question:

Given the tables:

```
AUCTION     USERNAME
--------    -------
Sotheby's   john
Christie's  john

USERNAME   FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
--------   --------  --------
john       John      Doe
john       John      Davis
```

, what do you want to be selected for `Sotheby's` and what for `Christie's`?

It's impossible to understand what do you mean by "*a way to run a query limiting to 1 record per username*" unless you answer this question.

**Update:**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    users
WHERE   username IN
        (
        SELECT  username
        FROM    auctions
        WHERE   category = 'category3'
        )
```

**Update 2:**

Does this query return something?

```
SELECT  u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname
FROM    auctions a, users u
WHERE   a.category = 'fake'
        AND u.username = a.username
```

**Update 3:**

```
SELECT  ao.username, u.firstname, u.lastname
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT username
        FROM    auctions a
        WHERE   category = 'fake'
        ) ao
LEFT JOIN
        users u
ON      u.username = a.username
```

Comment: Aye, I just put that as a comment on his original post.

Comment: It returns: #1052 - Column 'username' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: ahh, it still returned a 0 result set

Comment: This means there are no actual users for the 'fake' category. Select all usernames from auctions in 'fake' category and make sure it's the case. The query in `Update` actually does what you need.

Comment: Most DBMS would require either a.username or u.username in the SELECT list, even though they're equivalent. Update 2 certainly looks as though it should return the correct data - are you sure your data is as you say? What do you get from SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Auctions WHERE category = 'fake'?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AUCTIONS WHERE category = 'fake' returns 5.

Comment: Most probably, all username's are NULL for the auctions in the fake category, as nobody bothered to fill them.

Comment: Issue SELECT username FROM AUCTIONS WHERE category = 'fake' and see what the USERNAME's are. Then try to find these USERNAME's in actual USERS table.

Comment: Also try to run the query in `Update` against a real category, not the fake one.

Comment: The fake category is a real one..it is to do with fraudulent brands. The USERS table does not contain equivalent usersnames..I should have seen that straight of. That's why I want to grab the username from AUCTIONS and the rest of the data, filled in or not from USERS.

Comment: So what do you want to be returned for the 'fake' category?

Comment: I just have a column named category in auctions, which can be set to whatever I like. I want to select the username from auctions where category is equal to a paramter  I choose and that exists, and then select the fields from users for the same username.

Comment: To do this, I guess the username field in users would have to be filled in?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. You have a fake category in your table, with 5 records in it. Provided that no username from these records is actually contained in 'USERS', how many records do you want to be returned and what should be contained in these records?

Comment: I would want only the username from the fake category in auctions returned, and the blank fields from users returned

Comment: So you want five records with blank fields? Or one record with blank fields?

Comment: hmm, still duplicates. I am using SELECT ao.USERNAME, u.firstname, u.lastname FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT USERNAME FROM AUCTIONS a WHERE category = 'fake' )ao LEFT JOIN USERS u ON u.username = ao.USERNAME WHERE upper( ao.USERNAME ) LIKE '%b%' LIMIT 0 , 10 which gives a username twice

Comment: It seems to be based on how many records are in the USERS table

Comment: You said in your post: 'usernames are always unique'. Is it really so?

Comment: I mean, are usernames unique in table USERS? If not, then answer the question I asked in the very beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `SELECT`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood this right, using `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `SELECT` will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

English is not my native language but, if I understand correctly, you want to select all users (once) who has auction in given category x.

I am not sure if this syntax works for MySQL, but try something like:

```
SELECT
    AUCTIONS.USERNAME,
    USERS.firstname,
    USERS.lastname,
    USERS.flaggedauctions
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        AUCTIONS.USERNAME
    FROM
        AUCTIONS
    WHERE
        AUCTIONS.CATEGORY = x
) AS AUCTIONS
INNER JOIN 
    USERS
ON 
    USERS.USERNAME = AUCTIONS.USERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.username,
    u.firstname,
    u.lastname
FROM 
    Users u
RIGHT JOIN
    Auctions a
    ON
    u.username = a.username
WHERE
    a.category = 'category3'
```